# How to insert object in nested array?

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I'm new with AngularJS and right now I'm trying to insert a new object in nested array and I'm not sure how it's done. Here I have example of /sites/100820 (<-- site id). I'm trying to add a new object called icon in status right under the text and value. If you guys know how it should be done then I would be appreciated if you share your knowledge with me!

```
{
"siteId": 100820,
"siteName": "Pumppaamo 01",
"measuringPoints": [{
    "id": 102395,
    "name": "Pumppu 2",
    "measuringSubjects": [{
        "id": 110313,
        "name": "Käyntivirta",
        "latestResult": 6.2700000000000005,
        "latestDigitalResultText": null,
        "digital": 0,
        "latestReceived": "2008-11-10T04:00:22Z",
        "unit": "A",
        "latestResultAndUnit": "6.3 A",
        "numberOfDecimals": 1,
        "minValue": 0,
        "maxValue": 30,
        "alarmLevels": [{
            "id": 103765,
            "onLevel": 3,
            "onEventTypeId": 3,
            "offLevel": 3.187,
            "offEventTypeId": 7,
            "direction": "l",
            "onLevelEventText": "Alivirtahälytys",
            "offLevelEventText": "Alivirtahälytys poistunut",
            "offDelay": 60,
            "onDelay": 60,
            "onEventTypeText": "Limit 1 ON",
            "offEventTypeText": "Limit 1 OFF"
        }, {
            "id": 103766,
            "onLevel": 10,
            "onEventTypeId": 4,
            "offLevel": 9,
            "offEventTypeId": 8,
            "direction": "u",
            "onLevelEventText": "Ylivirtahälytys",
            "offLevelEventText": "Ylivirtahälytys poistunut",
            "offDelay": 60,
            "onDelay": 60,
            "onEventTypeText": "Limit 2 ON",
            "offEventTypeText": "Limit 2 OFF"
        }],
        "status": {
            "value": "OK",
            "text": "Ok",
            !RIGHT HERE!
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will asume you are trying this from javascript in the front-end:

```
var obj = //this var is your object above;

obj.measuringPoints[0].measuringSubjects[0].status.icon = {/*your new object*/};
```

- `measuringPoints[0]` is an array 0 is the desired index, your sample object only has one value
- `measuringSubjects[0]` the second level array that contains your object
- `status` is the desired property of the object

Comment: think you're gonna need `measuringSubjects` in there!